# get a column value from a table and assign it ot a scalar variable on SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get a column value from a table on SQL server 2008.

```
DECLARE @result TABLE 
(
  val FLOAT
);
insert into @result (val)
(
    select SUM(c)/10 val from atable
)

DECLARE @myval float 
SELECT @myval  = @result.val  # error : Must declare the scalar variable "@result". !!!

      if @myval = null
      begin 
  select @myval
      end
```

Why ?

thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is

```
SELECT @myval  = val FROM @result
```

But I think creating a table is an overkill here. You can do simple

```
select @myval = SUM(c)/10 from atable
```

If I understend you correctly.

Or if you simple return result of the sum, just do

```
select SUM(c)/10 from atable
```

to get the result back to the caller without any additional perturbations.